# Recursive addition in F# using

Tags: syntax, f#

I'm trying to implement the following recursive definition for addition in F#

m + 0 := m

m + (n + 1) := (m + n) + 1

I can't seem to get the syntax correct, The closest I've come is

```
let rec plus x y =                        
 match y with                     
 | 0 -> x;                        
 | succ(y) -> succ( plus(x y) );
```

Where succ n = n + 1. It throws an error on pattern matching for succ.

Comment: succ(y) is a function call, you cannot use it in pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what `succ` means in your example, but it is not a pattern defined in the standard F# library. Using just the basic functionality, you'll need to use a pattern that matches any number and then subtract one (and add one in the body):

```
let rec plus x y =                         
 match y with                      
 | 0 -> x                     
 | y -> 1 + (plus x (y - 1))
```

In F# (unlike e.g. in Prolog), you can't use your own functions inside patterns. However, you can define  *active patterns* that specify how to decompose input into various cases. The following takes an integer and returns either `Zero` (for zero) or `Succ y` for value `y + 1`:

```
let (|Zero|Succ|) n = 
  if n < 0 then failwith "Unexpected!"
  if n = 0 then Zero else Succ(n - 1)
```

Then you can write code that is closer to your original version:

```
let rec plus x y =
  match y with
  | Zero -> x
  | Succ y -> 1 + (plus x y)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Tomas said, you can't use `succ` like this without declaring it. What you can do is to create a discriminated union that represents a number:

```
type Number = 
| Zero
| Succ of Number
```

And then use that in the `plus` function:

```
let rec plus x y =
 match y with
 | Zero -> x
 | Succ(y1) -> Succ (plus x y1)
```

Or you could declare it as the `+` operator:

```
let rec (+) x y =
 match y with
 | Zero -> x
 | Succ(y1) -> Succ (x + y1)
```

If you kept `y` where I have `y1`, the code would work, because the second `y` would hide the first one. But I think doing so makes the code confusing.

Comment: I guess plus parameters are integers, which wont work with this Number type

Comment: If they were integers, there would be no need to implement addition this way, no?

Comment: Yes, but this is just a example to try out recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

```
type N = Zero | Succ of N

let rec NtoInt n =
  match n with
  | Zero -> 0
  | Succ x -> 1 + NtoInt x

let rec plus x y =
  match x with
  | Zero -> y
  | Succ n -> Succ (plus n y)
```

**DEMO:**

```
> plus (Succ (Succ Zero)) Zero |> NtoInt ;;
val it : int = 2
> plus (Succ (Succ Zero)) (Succ Zero) |> NtoInt ;;
val it : int = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec plus x y =
    match y with
    | 0 -> x
    | _ -> plus (x+1) (y-1)
```

Comment: The point here is to declare the addition operation, not use existing operations. See [Peano arithmetic on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_arithmetic#Arithmetic).